# Can I store some data permanently in a variable once initialized?

Tags: php, forms, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I have a form which has two input field called firstname and lastname with a submit button called 
submit. The input fields use twitter's typeahead.js with custom event trigger (typeahead:selected)

Thus, when the firstname is selected from the dropdown, I have a ajax call in the trigger which post the 
enrollment no of the selected person to another php page(xyz.php).

Here on xyz.php 
If I store that enrollment number in a variable
`$link = POST['number'];`

Now this works just fine.

But the problem is when I click my button I have another AJAX call to the same php file. 
And now I cannot use $link. It says Notice: Undefined index: number

Is there anyway I can get my variable to store the data permanently?

Comment: You'll need to store it in a database, or the session, depending on how long you want it to be available for.

Comment: Maybe include the value in the second post as well?  Each page request is its own context, completely building up the server-side code each time.  So unless you persist the value somewhere outside the code (session and database are common approaches), you'll need to provide the value again.  (Note: If all you do the first time is store the value, then maybe the first post isn't even needed?  Just include the value in the second post.)

Comment: Http doesn't inherently allow for persistence. You need to have either a database, write your data to a file, or store it in a session variable to achieve what you want. [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure)

Comment: I think I'll have to dig deep in sessions first. So, as soon as the user selects his name from the dropdown of the input field a ajax call will be made to another file where I would have to use the $_Session['enrollmentno'] and then I want this session to end as soon as the user enters a new name. When should I place my session_destroy()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use session on the server side to store data across requests. 
You can find more information here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions or a text file or a cookie, it depends your needs.